# Select optional navigation property into new object

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a set of business objects and I am trying to populate those objects with an Entity Framework query.  The MS-SQL database and EF model both mirror the classes below.

Note that `ParentType` is related by "0..1 to Many" with `ChildType`.

The problem is that I want to load a `ParentType` object as a Property of the `ChildType` object, but as written, if the `ParentType` is Null, I get `InvalidOperationException` because the materialized values in `ParentType` are Null.

Also note, I do not want to flatten the `ParentType` data into nullable fields in `ChildType` because later I want to group the resultant list by the entire `ParentType` object.

```
Public Class ParentType
    Public Property ParentTypeID as Integer
    Public Property Description as String
End Class

Public Class ChildType
    Public Property ChildTypeID As Integer
    Public Property ParentTypeID As Integer?
    Public Property Description As String

    Public Property ParentType As ParentType

    Public Shared Function GetChildTypes() As IQueryable(Of ChildType)
        Dim db As New DataAccess.MyModelEntities()

        Return (
            From c In db.ChildTypes
            Select New ChildType With {
                .ChildTypeID = c.ChildTypeTypeID,
                .ParentTypeID = c.ParentTypeID,
                .Description = c.Description,
                .ParentType = New ParentType With {
                    .ParentTypeID = c.ParentType.ParentTypeID,
                    .Description = c.ParentType.Description
                }
            }
        )
    End Function
End Class
```

Edit: Trying to clarify, what I am looking for is a way I can do `New ParentType` as written, but only when c.ParentType is not null.

Comment: Why doesn't `ParentType` have a property `ChildTypes`?

Comment: Because when I am using ParentType I never have a need for the ChildType collection; If I did I would add it in.

Comment: OK, I think I'm just figuring out what you're trying to achieve. It's bad practice to initialize a context inside an entity type which itself is initialized by another context. What don't you just use `db.ChildTypes.Include("ParentType")` when you get ChildTypes?

Comment: @GertArnold I'm not sure what you mean by "initialize a context inside an entity type which itself is intialized by another context", since the only context involved is `DataAccess.MyModelEntities` "db".  The other types (`ParentType`, `ChildType`) are just POCO's with no EF association at all.

Comment: Well, that's far from obvious from your code. All I see is `ChildType` and `db.ChildTypes`. How should I conclude they're different types? And how do you "load a `ParentType` object as a property of the `ChildType` object"? Sounds like loading by EF. Your question is utterly unclear. Anyway, this code doesn't belong inside a business class.

Comment: @GertArnold you're probably right about that.  I am just attempting to make do with the existing architecture.  I would love to have a chat with you about it if you're willing.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I guess I will have to allow the `ParentType` object to be created and allow all of its members to be nullable.  For me this isn't the ideal solution but it makes the query work as written.

```
Public Class ParentType
    Public Property ParentTypeID as Integer?
    Public Property Description as String
End Class
```

Instead of checking for `ParentType Is Nothing`, I can instead check for `ParentType.ParentTypeID.HasValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, man - I have struggled with this myself in the past.

In entity framework, basically it saves navigational properties as a foreign key.  Which means when you load an entity that has a navigational property it does not also load the properties of the entity that is that property's type because all it has is the foreign key.

If you want to load the properties of the related entity, you have to either Include that in your query using say Eager Loading (the example Gert Arnold used), or query the other table itself in the process.

In your particular case, I'm guessing you would use something like this:

```
From c In db.ChildTypes
            Select New ChildType With {
                .ChildTypeID = c.ChildTypeTypeID,
                .ParentTypeID = c.ParentTypeID,
                .Description = c.Description,
                .ParentType = New ParentType With {
                    .ParentTypeID = c.ParentTypeID,
                    .Description = (From parent In db.ParentTypes Select parent.Description Where parent.ParentTypeID = c.ParentTypeID).FirstOrDefault()
                }
```

Or the Eager Loading way as Gert recommends:

```
Dim childTypesList = db.ChildTypes.Include("ParentTypes").ToListAsync()
```

Comment: Hm... problem with the code above is that ParentTypeID and indeed, the entire c.ParentType object, is sometimes null.  I certainly don't want to run a subquery for each property, and even if I did I would still have to assign the value into nullable properties, one of the things I'd like to avoid.